# Unlock Android encrypted DISK IMAGE FILE of SD card on desktop Linux

Tags: linux, sd-card, dm-crypt

I am able to successfully unlock a corrupted Android encrypted SD card on desktop Linux using instructions from the Internet.

```
# dmsetup create crypt5 --table "0 `blockdev --getsize /dev/mmcblk0p2` crypt aes-cbc-essiv:sha256 HEXIDECIMALPASSPHRASEHERE 0 /dev/mmcblk0p2 0"
```

Recovery directly from the SD card using photorec was taking an unacceptable amount of time. As a compromise, I decided to start by making a disk image file from the encrypted partition so I can verify the integrity of the SD card an reuse it then recover the data from the image file later.

```
# dd if=/dev/mmcblk0p2 of=/home/crash/Documents/128gb.img iflag=direct oflag=dsync
```

Now the question is, "how do I unlock the disk image file?" Knowing that the disk image file is supposed to be identical to the original partition, I tried tweaking the original command to plug in the size of the block device and the location of disk image file.

```
# blockdev --getsize /dev/mmcblk0p2
```

Result:

```
250048479
```

Plug that in:

```
# dmsetup create crypt6 --table "0 250048479 crypt aes-cbc-essiv:sha256 HEXIDECIMALPASSPHRASEHERE 0 /home/crash/Documents/128gb.img 0"
```

This fails with the following error:

```
device-mapper: reload ioctl on crypt6 failed: Invalid argument
Command failed
```

I don't see what went wrong. I would like to confirm that this disk image can be unlocked before I move on to wiping and testing the SD card.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine that you need to convert your image file to a block device before `dmcrypt` can handle it. Here we use the `loop` device, which allows us to present a block interface to the named file:

```
# Create a loop device and capture its name
lodev=$(losetup --show --find /home/crash/Documents/128gb.img)
echo "Using device $lodev for the image" >&2

# Map the crypto layer on to the loop block device
dmsetup create crypt6 --table "0 250048479 crypt aes-cbc-essiv:sha256 HEXIDECIMALPASSPHRASEHERE 0 $lodev 0"

...
# Delete the loop device when we have finished with it
losetup -d "$lodev"
```

Actually, using this configuration you could replace your constant `250048479` with a call back to `blockdev` (notice I'm also using the more modern `$(...)` rather than backticks `` `...` ``):

```
dmsetup create crypt6 --table "0 $(blockdev --getsize "$lodev") crypt aes-cbc-essiv:sha256 HEXIDECIMALPASSPHRASEHERE 0 $lodev 0"
```

Comment: `dmsetup create` gives me `device-mapper: reload ioctl on crypt6  failed: Das Argument ist ungültig
Command failed` - any idea how to solve that?

Comment: @Qohelet you'd first need to check that the value of `$lodev` is correct, and that `blockdev --getsize "$lodev"` returns something sensble.